# Editable ComboBox cleared when i pressed space or arrow buttons - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox, keyevent

I am making a Editable ComboBox which show any values contain the input and it works fine.

But the problem is in the input field, whenever i typed Space or arrow buttons the input field keep reseting.

I tried setonKeyPressed and setonKeyTyped too but it isn't solve the problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        
        ObservableList<String> fruit = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        fruit.add("apple");
        fruit.add("orange");
        fruit.add("banana");

        ComboBox myComboBox = new ComboBox();
        myComboBox.setEditable(true);
        myComboBox.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                myComboBox.getItems().clear();
                myComboBox.show();
                String input = myComboBox.getEditor().getText();
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < fruit.size(); i++) {
                    if(fruit.get(i).contains(input)) {      //Check if the list contains the input
                        myComboBox.getItems().add(fruit.get(i));    
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        HBox hbox = new HBox(myComboBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hbox, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra i just edited my question again. It was my first time making question here so sorry to watse your time. I will take any advices that make my question better or to solve this problem

Comment: what do you expect to happen if you explicitly clear the items on _any_ key released ;) Work through a tutorial on how to use keyEvents, and apply what you learned after re-thinking the logic of your handler.